# How do I report Errata?

Tags: sheet-music

I have come across instances of errors in scores (in editions I otherwise really like) that I can obviously correct for myself. The problems are twofold: First, it makes me wonder where the other errors - and the ones I might not find would be. Second, it'd obviously be better for somebody to be able to web search '[isbn] errata' for a list of all that's been found. I get that this is a problem with all of publishing (maybe not a good fit for music.stackexchange), but musical errors can have a much bigger impact: Most typos are the difference between a slur ending on this note or that, but a wrong accidental is the difference between 'blue' and 'orange' (and a wrong time signature, or an incomplete measure is like the difference between 'green' and 'recidivism').

Look, there's nothing to be ashamed of - there are a million notes to check on - it'd just be nice if there were errata, and I want to know how to report what I've found.

Answer (score 5):

Send a note to the publisher and, if possible, the author/editor. I’ve done this a handful of times, and in each case the error was corrected in the next edition. (Plus, they put my name in the acknowledgments, which was cool.)

The problem of score-engraving errors, by the way, is one reason that many musicians own multiple editions of the same piece. It’s also why scholarly editions include notes on the choices of editorial decisions, often discussion historical errors or uncertainties.